# Why is Flask-Mail actually sending messages during testing

Tags: testing, flask, flask-mail

I have the following test in my app:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('database')
def test_reset_email(client):
    assert current_app.config['TESTING']
    with mail.record_messages() as outbox:
        response = client.post('/reset', data=dict(email=tconst.ADMIN_EMAIL),
                               follow_redirects=True)
        msg = outbox[-1]
        assert const.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUEST_FLASH in str(response.data)
        assert msg.subject == const.RESET_EMAIL_SUBJECT
        assert 'Reset Password' in msg.html
        assert 'Reset Password' in msg.body
        pattern = ('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*'
                   + '\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+')  # noqa W605
        url = re.findall(pattern, msg.body)[0]
        path = urlparse(url).path
        response = client.post(path, data=dict(password='newpass'), follow_redirects=True)
        log_in(client, tconst.ADMIN_EMAIL, 'newpass')
        assert 'Logout' in str(response.data)
```

According to the documentation if the `app.config['TESTING']` is `True`, emails will be suppressed. The test suite passes, but the email message is actually sent.

```
@user_blueprint.route('/reset', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reset():
    """Sends a tokenized email link to the user. Fails silently if email doesn't exist."""
    form = ResetPasswordForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        email = form.email.data
        user = User.select_by_email(email=email).first()
        if user:
            timed_serializer = URLSafeTimedSerializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
            token = timed_serializer.dumps(email, salt='recovery-token')
            url = url_for('user.reset_with_token', token=token, _external=True)
            body = render_template('email/recover.txt', url=url)
            html = render_template('email/recover.html', url=url)
            msg = Message(body=body, html=html, recipients=[email],
                          subject=const.RESET_EMAIL_SUBJECT)
            mail.send(msg)
        flash(const.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUEST_FLASH, 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('user.login'))
    return render_template('user/reset.html', form=form)
```

I've also tried setting the app's config's `MAIL_SUPPRESS_SEND` to `True` (as well as `False`, which fails the `assert`).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer was in how I was creating the Flask app. The `pytest` fixture created the app, which had the default (i.e., production) configuration, which means it wasn't in test mode when the `mail` object was created, and when I updated the configuration after app creation, the `mail` object didn't know about it. The solution was to pass the `create_app` the config from the `pytest` fixture.

```
def create_app(config=None):
    ...
    config = config or os.getenv('APP_SETTINGS', 'app.ProdConfig')
    app.config.from_object(config)
    ...

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def app():
    app = create_app(config='app.TestConfig')
    ...
```